# Restrict users on multisite WordPress install

Tags: multisite, user-roles, permissions, user-access

I have a series of sites that I maintain as part of a WordPress multisite install.  I'd like to be able to create users accounts that are restricted to viewing only a single one of these sites.  Is this possible?

Once this is accomplished, is there a way to determine this permission status programmatically?  I'd like to be able to get a list of all the sites the current user has access to, or at the very least, test if the user has permission to access a specific site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `is_user_member_of_blog()` to check if the current user has been assigned to the blog in `wp-admin/network/site-users.php`. Then hook into `template_redirect` and run the test:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

    if ( ! is_user_member_of_blog() )   
        die( 'Please ask the network administrator to get access to this blog.' );
});
```