# Allow users on a multisite network to only have access to one subdomain

Tags: multisite

I have a multisite set up, and i want each subdomain to work independently from the rest, while allowing only allowing network admins to have access to all sites.

But at the moment, if user a logs into one of the sites in one of the subdomains, and visits another site on a seperate subdomain, he is already automaticaly logged into that site. Even though, when i check out the user panel in each site, they do have a distinct list of users for each one.

Is there a way to do that? Make each site work autonomously as far as the user is concerned.

Comment: The behavior you're wanting is actually the normal WP behavior; by default, users only have access to whatever site they were created in. Did you create all your users in the network admin or did you create them in the individual sub-sites?

Comment: Ive read conflicting reports on this. For example this article https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/why-you-should-not-use-wordpress-multisite.html

Comment: and tried to specificaly create a user on an individual sub site and logged into that site, and he was still logged into to the other ones, even though he doesnt appear in that other sites user list

Comment: Maybe it's because I also use an authentication plugin, and it handles per-site access. Looks like you could use this code snippet: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84506/restrict-users-on-multisite-wordpress-install

Comment: Thanks for your help, i checked out the snippet, but im not sure its what im looking for, its close, but i dont want to restrict access to the other sites, i just dont want them to be automaticaly logged into the other sites.... once a user logs into one of them, the login box dissapears on the rest of the sites. I would like the login box to still be visible.